# SQL Server query slow when paginated

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012

I am seeing some strange behaviour with the following T-SQL query in SQL Server 2012:

```
SELECT Id 
FROM dbo.Person 
WHERE CONTAINS(Name, '"John" AND "Smith"')
ORDER BY Name
```

Executing this query alone gives me about 1,300 results in less than two seconds (there's a fulltext index on `Name`)

However, when I change the query to this:

```
SELECT Id 
FROM dbo.Person 
WHERE CONTAINS(Name, '"John" AND "Smith"')
ORDER BY Name
OFFSET 0 rows
FETCH NEXT 10 ROWS ONLY
```

It takes more than 20 seconds to give me 10 results.

The following query is even worse:

```
SELECT Id 
FROM ( 
    SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY Name) AS RowNum, Id 
    FROM dbo.Person
    WHERE CONTAINS(Name, '"John" AND "Smith"') ) AS RowConstrainedResult 
WHERE RowNum >= 0 AND RowNum < 11 
ORDER BY RowNum
```

It takes more than 1.5 minutes to complete!

Any ideas?

### Slow plan

[image: Slow]

### Fast plan

[image: Fast]

Comment: What happens if you change your second query to `SELECT TOP 10 * .... ORDER BY Name`?

Comment: On what columns is index IX_PersonSearch... made? You're getting a key lookup because you're selecting * from the table and the used index does not contain all the output columns. I think you should select only the columns you need and then include them in the non-clustered index as included columns, not index columns.

Comment: Can you post you indexes on the table (create script)?

Comment: @thecoon Sorry, I wrote that incorrectly while simplifying. I'm only selecting Id (the PK) in the actual query.

Comment: @thecoon - Its still weird that the plans are so different when both of them have an `ORDER BY` the same column

Comment: @vrs: Then please include the `id` column in the IX_PersonSearch index and make another test. Should be far better now.

Comment: @PeterKiss All columns are indexed (Nonclustered), only the Id is indexed clustered as this is a Cachetable for fast searching. (At least it's supposed to be :) )

Comment: @Lamak: I think the paging breaks it, not the `ORDER BY`. Never used the 2012 paging myself, but the query plan indicates towards this.

Comment: @thecoon Yes, I'm pretty sure the paging breaks it: Without paging, it's blazing fast. And I'm not sure where I should put the index you were mentioning since all columns are indexed and I'm only selecting the Id.

Comment: @vrs: Actually, let me wait for the new query plan. I take back what I said :) (about it being better).

Comment: @thecoon Sorry, what new query plan? Do you need more information?

Comment: @vrs: yes, but since that particular index contains only the `Name` column, it also has to do a key lookup on the clustered index in order to retrieve the id. So including the ID in the non-clustered index should remove the key lookup operator.

Comment: The ID is always included in every nonclustered index. This is the way SQL Server is able to to key lookups (by ID).

Comment: @usr: touche! can we see the key lookup arguments (just hover over it).

Comment: What I forgot to mention: When i do the same query with LIKE instead of CONTAINS, is fast, too. (Paginated or not)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I managed to solve the problem:

As I said in the question there were indizes on all columns + statistics for each column. (Because of legacy LIKE queries)
I removed all indizes and statistics, added the fulltext search and voilà, the query became really fast.

It seems the indizes led to a different Execution Plan.

Thank you all very much for your help!

Comment: Well deleting the index entirely is one way of preventing it from being used I guess!

Answer (score 7):

As you just want the `TOP 10` ordered by name it thinks it will be quicker to work down the index on `name` in order and look to see if each row matches the `CONTAINS(Name, '"John" AND "Smith"') )` predicate.

Presumably it takes many more rows to find the 10 matches required then it expects and this cardinality issue is compounded by the number of key lookups.

A quick hack to stop it using this plan would be to change the `ORDER BY` to `ORDER BY Name + ''` although using `CONTAINSTABLE` in conjunction with `FORCE ORDER` should also work.

Answer (score 3):

This looks like classic selectivity misestimation. Not sure what can be done about it as the "driver" of the query is fulltext search which you cannot augment with statistics.

Try rewriting the `where contains` predicate to an `inner join containstable` ([CONTAINSTABLE](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189760.aspx)) and apply join order hints to force the shape of the plan.

That is not a perfect solution because it has maintenance issues, but I cannot see another way.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I tried it. Same result though: When not using pagination, the query is really fast. When Paginating it suddenly becomes really slow again :/

Comment: Ok can you post the plan as an image and your query? My guess it that we didn't yet succeed to generate the desired shape.